# Accidentally mounted an ISO directly to /media, and I'm unsure how to unmount

Tags: iso, media

I mounted an installation ISO directly into /media on a 64-bit Fedora-16 machine using

```
# mount -o loop isodisk.iso /media
```

It returned mount: `warning: /media seems to be mounted read-only`

Now /media has all the setup files in it. I believe I should have created a new directory within /media and mounted there so that I could easily unmount.

I'm quite new to linux, and the last time I started messing around with unmounting /media/ on my personal Ubuntu machine it took me a while to fix everything. Can I safely unmount /media/ and reboot without any repercussions?

Comment: `umount /media` should be fine. I don't know why `/media` was mounted the other time you're talking about, but I can't think of any reason why unmounting it would have caused problems. It also shouldn't be necessary to reboot.

Comment: Alrighty, great, thanks. I just remember something about having to mess around with some stuff with fstab. Perhaps that problem was specific to what I was doing, or I'm just misremembering things.

Answer (score 0):

Just unmount it. You can't break a system by merely unmounting something, except in highly unusual configurations: if any file on a filesystem is in use, the unmount operation will fail.

If you can't or don't want to unmount `/media`, but you want to access the directory tree that the mounted filesystem is shadowing, you can move the mount point somewhere else. Create an empty directory (or if you prefer, use an existing one) then call `mount --move`. This is a Linux feature.

```
mkdir /mnt
mount --move /media /mnt
```